# How to get a Vec from polars Series or ChunkedArray?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

In Rust Polars, how to cast a `Series` or `ChunkedArray` to a `Vec`?

Answer (score 6):

You can `collect` the values into a `Vec`.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let s = Series::new("a", 0..10i32);

    let as_vec: Vec<Option<i32>> = s.i32()?.into_iter().collect();

    // if we are certain we don't have missing values
    let as_vec: Vec<i32> = s.i32()?.into_no_null_iter().collect();
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: How can I do this for str type? I am getting error if I do this ...```let asvec: Vec<_> = self.se.str()?.into_iter().collect(); 
   |                                             ^^^^^^ method not found in `polars::prelude::Series````

Comment: OK I found [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/docs/eager/index.html) that for str values, replace ```i32()``` with ```utf8()```!

Comment: @ritchie46 is there a way to do this without knowing the type of the series?

Answer (score 1):

If your series [contains `PolarsNumericType` values](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/datatypes/trait.PolarsNumericType.html#implementors), you can use [`to_vec`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#method.to_vec) or [`to_vec_null_aware`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/chunked_array/struct.ChunkedArray.html#method.to_vec_null_aware) depending on the `null` values.

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main(){
    let series = Series::new("col", &[Some(1), Some(2), Some(3)]);
    if series.null_count() == 0 {
        println!("{:?}", series.i32().unwrap().to_vec_null_aware().left().unwrap())
    } else {
        println!("{:?}", series.i32().unwrap().to_vec()); 
    }
}
```

`to_vec()` will convert the `series` into *`Vec` of `Option<i32>`*. But `to_vec_null_aware` will convert `series` into `Vec<i32>` if there are no null values.